# Git history starting from a specific commit up to the last commit

Tags: git

I know I can use the following command to get commit history starting from this specific commit to the first commit in history (going backwards).

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" "de37b49d8f06321275079e6b3a3f00aa22bbff99"
```

However, how to reverse this to display history starting from this specific commit -including it- up to the last commit in history (going upwards)?

Thanks

Comment: by "last commit" do you mean HEAD?

Comment: Yes, the latest commit..HEAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming de37b49 isn't a merge commit you would do

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" de37b49~1..HEAD
```

which is saying "NOT reachable by parent of de37b49" but "reachable by HEAD"

If that is a merge commit, then you would need to use

```
git log ... ^de37b49^1 ^de37b49^2 HEAD
```

(for as many parents it has, presuming 2)

Comment: Thanks, I think there is a typo where "$s" should be "%s"

Comment: sorry, I'll fix that.  I hand typed it instead of copy/paste

Comment: also this doesn't include the current commit so I will have to use in in combination with something like this (git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" 6a2646117df93da73c4395987502ac7b9c31bec3 -1)

Comment: The ~1 after the SHA should have made it include the current commit.